Global sections of tangent sheaf of singular varieties
Let $X\subset \mathbf{P}^{n+1}$ be a $n$-dimensional normal hypersurface of degree $3$, and we denote its tangent sheaf by $T_X$. We further assume that $n\geq 4$.
When $X$ is smooth, it is known that $H^0(X, T_X)=0$, see e.g. Huybrechts' book on cubic hypersurfaces.
Question: How about singular $X$? For example, when $X$ has only one ordinary double point as singularities, is it still true that $H^0(X, T_X)=0$?

Having thought about this question for a substantial amount of time, a satisfactory (complete) answer still eludes me. Some basic observations:

If $X$ is a cone over a smooth cubic in $\mathbf{P}_{n}$, then $H^{0}(T_{X})\neq 0$.
If $X$ is the chordal cubic fourfold, then $H^{0}(T_{X})\neq 0$.
If $X$ is a cubic with fourfold with isolated ADE singularities, then $H^{0}(T_{X})=0$ (this follows from a result of Laza, which says that such cubics are GIT stable).
If $X$ is a cubic with a single ordinary double point, then $H^{0}(T_{X})=0$ holds (see Proposition 4.1 in this paper - I wish I had a different reference; if you find one, let me know - this is certainly well-known to experts).


To prove the equality $H^0(T_X) = 0$ it is enough to check that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is discrete. In the case where $X$ has an ordinary double point this is easy. Indeed, the linear projection from the singular point gives a birational isomorphism of $X$ onto the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^n$ in a smooth complete intersection $Y$ of a quadric and a cubic. The naturality of this construction proves that $$\mathrm{Aut}(X) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(Y),$$ and the latter group is discrete for $n \ge 2$.

@Sasha That's an interesting perspective. Your comment applies to the situation when $X$ has exactly one odp, but if it has $m$ odps, then the associated $(2,3)$-complete intersection has $m-1$ odps, I think. So it would be natural to ask: what happens for $m>1$? Surely we expect $H^{0}(T_{X})=0$ to hold in that situation too.
